# Numpy: Divide each row by a vector element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have a numpy array:

```
data = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
```

and I have a corresponding "vector:"

```
vector = np.array([1,2,3])
```

How do I operate on `data` along each row to either subtract or divide so the result is:

```
sub_result = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
div_result = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]
```

Long story short: How do I perform an operation on each row of a 2D array with a 1D array of scalars that correspond to each row?

Comment: if I have a 3x1000 array and try to divide by a 3-elt array, I get an error. Why doesn't this just work?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Here you go. You just need to use `None` (or alternatively `np.newaxis`) combined with broadcasting:

```
In [6]: data - vector[:,None]
Out[6]:
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

In [7]: data / vector[:,None]
Out[7]:
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) is the doc.

Comment: a [visual example](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/numpy/python-numpy-exercise-96.php)

Comment: @user108569 using the latest version of numpy (1.18.1), `None` still works equivalently to `np.newaxis`. I'm not sure what your setup is, or the exact issue you are experiencing, but the answer is still valid.

Comment: Using reshape as suggested by another answer might be better because jax also has a reshape function. I believe it doesn't have numpy-like slicing though.

Comment: @sazary Perhaps a better explanation in the NumPy manual: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html . The link you provided points to the API reference which might be difficult to parse for newcomers.

Answer (score 19):

As has been mentioned, slicing with `None` or with `np.newaxes` is a great way to do this.
Another alternative is to use transposes and broadcasting, as in

```
(data.T - vector).T
```

and

```
(data.T / vector).T
```

For higher dimensional arrays you may want to use the `swapaxes` method of NumPy arrays or the NumPy `rollaxis` function.
There really are a lot of ways to do this.

For a fuller explanation of broadcasting, see
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 10):

Adding to the answer of stackoverflowuser2010, in the general case you can just use

```
data = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])

vector = np.array([1,2,3])

data / vector.reshape(-1,1)
```

This will turn your vector into a `column matrix/vector`. Allowing you to do the elementwise operations as you wish. At least to me, this is the most intuitive way going about it and since (in most cases) numpy will just use a view of the same internal memory for the reshaping it's efficient too.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Creating a column vector with `.reshape(-1,1)`  is the most intuitive way to use broadcasting.

Comment: It should be the accepted answer because jax also has a reshape function. I believe it doesn't have numpy-like slicing though.

Answer (score 9):

Pythonic way to do this is ...

```
np.divide(data.T,vector).T
```

This takes care of reshaping and also the results are in floating point format.
In other answers results are in rounded integer format.

**#NOTE:** No of columns in both data and vector should match

Comment: Note: This does not do what the OP is requesting. The end result is array([[1., 0.5, 0.33333333], [2., 1., 0.66666667], [3. , 1.5, 1. ]]). It might be 'Pythonic' but it's incorrect.

Comment: @MarkCramer Thank you. I have corrected my answer to provide the right result.

Comment: This is correct but no longer pythonic. It is bizarre how numpy is so often elegant but then with things like this it is like...huh?

Answer (score 4):

JoshAdel's solution uses np.newaxis to add a dimension. An alternative is to use [reshape() to align the dimensions in preparation for broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
data = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
vector = np.array([1,2,3])

data
# array([[1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 2],
#        [3, 3, 3]])
vector
# array([1, 2, 3])

data.shape
# (3, 3)
vector.shape
# (3,)

data / vector.reshape((3,1))
# array([[1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1]])
```

Performing the reshape() allows the dimensions to line up for broadcasting:

```
data:            3 x 3
vector:              3
vector reshaped: 3 x 1
```

Note that `data/vector` is ok, but it doesn't get you the answer that you want. It divides each *column* of `array` (instead of each *row*) by each corresponding element of `vector`. It's what you would get if you explicitly reshaped `vector` to be `1x3` instead of `3x1`.

```
data / vector
# array([[1, 0, 0],
#        [2, 1, 0],
#        [3, 1, 1]])
data / vector.reshape((1,3))
# array([[1, 0, 0],
#        [2, 1, 0],
#        [3, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 3):

The key is to reshape the vector of size (3,) to (3,1): divide each row by an element or (1,3): divide each column by an element. As data.shape does not correspond to vector.shape, NumPy automatically expands vector's shape to (3,3) and performs division, element-wise.

```py
In[1]: data/vector.reshape(-1,1)
Out[1]:
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])

In[2]: data/vector.reshape(1,-1)
Out[2]:
array([[1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333],
       [2.        , 1.        , 0.66666667],
       [3.        , 1.5       , 1.        ]])
```

Similar:

```py
x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
x
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

x/np.sum(x, axis=0, keepdims=True)
array([[0.        , 0.08333333, 0.13333333],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333],
       [0.66666667, 0.58333333, 0.53333333]])

x/np.sum(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
array([[0.        , 0.33333333, 0.66666667],
       [0.25      , 0.33333333, 0.41666667],
       [0.28571429, 0.33333333, 0.38095238]])

print(np.sum(x, axis=0).shape)
print(np.sum(x, axis=1).shape)
print(np.sum(x, axis=0, keepdims=True).shape)
print(np.sum(x, axis=1, keepdims=True).shape)
(3,)
(3,)
(1, 3)
(3, 1)
```