# Most efficient way to get the cooccurrence matrix in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, tuples

I wonder what would be the most efficient way to form the cooccurrence matrix in python if you have two list of tuples and their counts, like:

```
l1 = [(a, b, c, d), (b, c, d), (d, a)]
l2 = [(one, two), (two, three), (one)]
counts = [3, 7, 4]
```

And then, the outcome should be like this:

```
#     one     two     three
# a     7       3         0
# b     3      10         7
# c     3      10         7
# d     7      10         7
```

However, actual matrices (lists of tuples) and resulting matrix can be quite large.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please explain better, also sis you try anything?

Comment: I tried several things, but far from any success. I have not good direction about how to solve, except very "traditional", i.e., iterative or the like. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574257/constructing-a-co-occurance-matrix-in-python-pandas) looks similar, but it is not duplicate. I think the problem I posted here is more complicated.

Comment: Not a duplicate: this question does not require to use pandas