# Generate matrix of context or simple word vector embedding in Python

Tags: python, vector, scikit-learn, nlp, embed

I have two sentences:
`Skies are blue. Grass is green`

I would like to compute simple matrix of word vector space embedding or matrix of co-occurrences, I am not sure what proper terminology is. But here is that I want.
So I have 6 distinct words from two sentences above, so my matrix will be 6 by 6. Assume that my words have the following ordering corresponding to rows or column ordering: 0 - Skies, 1 - are, 2 - blue, 3 - Grass, 4 - is, 5 - green. Then I would like to count co-occurrence using size of window = 2 (meaning 2 words prior to current word and 2 words after current word).

- Element with index [0,0] will have value 0, since `Skies` do not
  co-occur with `Skies`.
- Element with index [0,1] will have value,
  since `are` occurs next to `Skies` only once
- Element with index [0,2]
  will have value, since `blue` occurs next to `Skies` only once.

So on and so forth. Is there scikit module for it? I looked at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562789/word-word-co-occurrence-matrix) , but it does not seem to answer my question.

**Update** This matrix is key object of distributional hypothesis.