# Scipy Correlation Matrix From Co-Occurance Matrix (For Topic Modeling Via Community Dectection)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nlp, statistics

Basically, I am trying to implement this...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sI7VpFNiy_I&t=20m

Another person was working on the step after what I am stuck here
[Second-order cooccurrence of terms in texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833387/second-order-cooccurrence-of-terms-in-texts)

My questions are...
Why is function "A" failing in my example?
How can I make function "A" work in my example?

In the above video, Thomas defines a function(below, function "A" ), which takes a co occurrence matrix and returns a correlation matrix.

I am just getting out of pandas land and into scipy, so I have no idea what is going on in the code, or if the code still works at all.

```
def _association_matrix(self,matrix):
    O=matrix.copy()
    #N compute expected matrix
    N=O.sum(1).sum()
    R=O.copy()
    R.data=np.ones(len(R.data))
    R.data=R.data/N
    
    Fx_old=np.array(O.sum(1).flatten())
    Fy_old=np.array(O.sum(0).flatten())
    
    Fx=spdiags(Fx_old,0,Fx_old.shape[0],Fx_old.shape[0])
    Fy=spdiags(Fy_old,0,Fy_old.shape[0],Fy_old.shape[0])
    
    Fx=Fx.tocsc()
    Fy=Fy.tocsc()
    
    E=Fx*R*Fy
    E.tocsc()
    
    #compute poisson association measure
    
    poi=E.copy()
    poi.data=(np.sign(O.data-E.data)*
              (O.data*np.log(O.data/E.data)-
              (O.data-E.data)))
    
    return poi
```

I have tried the code on a co occurrence matrix I made(code below) and I get the following error:
***ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5158) into shape (1)***

```
from nltk.corpus import state_union
StateofUnion=[]
for i in state_union.fileids():
    StateofUnion.append(state_union.raw(i))
import pandas as pd
#I didn't download most of nltk so just loading all of nltk isnt heavy for me, but would be heavy for most users
import nltk
years=pd.Series(state_union.fileids()).str.slice(stop=4)
presidents=pd.Series(state_union.fileids()).str.slice(start=5,stop=-4)
presidents=presidents.str.replace('|'.join(['1','2','-']),'')
party=[]
for i in presidents:
    if i=='Truman':
        party.append('dem')
    elif i=='Eisenhower':
        party.append('rep')
    elif i=='Kennedy':
        party.append('dem')
    elif i=='Johnson':
        party.append('dem')
    elif i=='Johnson-2':
        party.append('dem')
    elif i=='Johnson-1':
        party.append('dem')    
    elif i=='Nixon':
        party.append('rep')
    elif i=='Ford':
        party.append('rep')
    elif i=='Carter':
        party.append('dem')
    elif i=='Reagan':
        party.append('rep')
    elif i=='Bush':
        party.append('rep')
    elif i=='Bush-1':
        party.append('rep')
    elif i=='Bush-2':
        party.append('rep')
    elif i=='Clinton':
        party.append('dem')
    elif i=='GWBush':
        party.append('rep')
    elif i=='GWBush-1':
        party.append('rep')
    elif i=='GWBush-2':
        party.append('rep')    
fileid=pd.Series(state_union.fileids()).str.slice(stop=-4)        
SOUA=pd.DataFrame({'Address':StateofUnion,
              'Year':years,
                  'President':presidents,
                   'Party':party,
                  'recid':fileid})

#A simple cleaning function, yes it's bad- its also good enough for now
def scrub(pandascolumn):
    #assumes we are dealing with pandas
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
    stop = stopwords.words('english')
    #Destroys Sentence Tokenization
    badchars=['!', '@', '#','$', '%','ą','ś', 
              '^','&','\.',',','\'','\)',
              '\(','\[','\]','\?','\:',
              '\--','\;']
    pattern = '|'.join(badchars)
    return pandascolumn.str.lower().\
           str.replace(pattern,'').\
           apply(word_tokenize).\
           apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop]).\
           apply(' '.join)

SOUA=SOUA.set_index('recid')
SOUA['ScrubbedAddress']=scrub(SOUA['Address'])

def get_skip_bigram(Series,n,k):
    return Series.str.split().apply(lambda x: list(nltk.skipgrams(x, n, k)))

grams=get_skip_bigram(SOUA[SOUA['President']=='Clinton']['ScrubbedAddress'],2,1)


skiplist=[]
for i in range(0,len(grams)):
    for j in grams[i]:
        skiplist.append(list(j))

def get_vocab(doc):
    vocab=set()
    for i in range(0,len(doc)):
        vocab.update(doc[i])
    return vocab

vocab=get_vocab(skiplist)


import scipy.sparse as sp
voc2id = dict(zip(vocab,range(len(vocab))))
rows, cols, vals = [],[],[]
for r,d in enumerate(skiplist):
    for e in d:
        rows.append(r)
        cols.append(voc2id[e])
        vals.append(1)
X=sp.csc_matrix((vals,(rows,cols)))        


Xc=X.T*X
Xc.setdiag(0)
print(Xc.toarray())

from scipy import sparse
def _association_matrix(matrix):
    O=matrix.copy()
    #N compute expected matrix
    N=O.sum(1).sum()
    R=O.copy()
    R.data=np.ones(len(R.data))
    R.data=R.data/N
    
    
    Fx_old=np.array(O.sum(1).flatten())
    Fy_old=np.array(O.sum(0).flatten())
    
    
    Fx=spdiags(Fx_old,0,Fx_old.shape[0],Fx_old.shape[0])
    Fy=spdiags(Fy_old,0,Fy_old.shape[0],Fy_old.shape[0])
    
    Fx=Fx.tocsc()
    Fy=Fy.tocsc()
    
    E=Fx*R*Fy
    E.tocsc()
    
    #compute poisson association measure
    
    poi=E.copy()
    poi.data=(np.sign(O.data-E.data)*
              (O.data*np.log(O.data/E.data)-
              (O.data-E.data)))
    
    return poi

_association_matrix(Xc)
```

The part that is producing the error is "**Fx.tocsc()**", I do not understand why or how to fix the error.

Again, I have 2 pressing questions.
Why is function "**A**" failing in my example?
How can I make function "**A**" work in my example?

Beyond these 3, obviously an implementation of `Thomas's work flow` would be pretty nice for the topic modeling community. That's what we are working towards. If you can tackle that head on, even better. [topic model workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrjS9.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, "please explain this code to me" is off-topic for stack overflow. Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code and check the contents of the variables at each step? What are your _specific_ questions about the code? Regarding the error, it's pretty self-explanatory: you're trying to broadcast an array with a shape of `5818` into an array of shape `1`. You need to figure out why your input shape is not what you expect or how to make it match

Comment: @G.Anderson Alright nice point, I've removed "How does this work?".