# Python Pandas how to find top string which co-occurs?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have generated a co-occurrence matrix by using the Python pandas library, with the following code:

```
# dfdo is an ordered dictionary with a key called KEY453    

df = pd.DataFrame(dfdo).set_index('KEY453')
df_asint = df.astype(int)
com = df_asint.T.dot(df_asint)
```

It follows the same procedure as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574257/constructing-a-co-occurrence-matrix-in-python-pandas#20574460) question.

My question is, how can I find the top 2 strings which co-occur with a given string in the matrix?  For example, The top 2 strings that co-occur with Dog in the example below are Cat and Zebra.

```
       Cat  Dog Zebra
Cat     0    2    3
Dog     2    0    1
Zebra   3    1    0
```

Comment: Do you think `df.idxmax()` ?

Comment: jezrael: edited for more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
print (df.loc['Dog'].nlargest(2))
Cat      2
Zebra    1
Name: Dog, dtype: int64

print (df.loc['Dog'].nlargest(2).index)
Index(['Cat', 'Zebra'], dtype='object')
```

If need all values of `DataFrame` use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
print (np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, :2])
[[2 1]
 [0 2]
 [0 1]]

print (df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, :2]])
Index([['Zebra', 'Dog'], ['Cat', 'Zebra'], ['Cat', 'Dog']], dtype='object')

print (pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, :2]], 
                               index=df.index, 
                               columns=['first','second']))

       first second
Cat    Zebra    Dog
Dog      Cat  Zebra
Zebra    Cat    Dog
```

or `apply`:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.nlargest(2).index, index=['first','second']), axis=1))
       first second
Cat    Zebra    Dog
Dog      Cat  Zebra
Zebra    Cat    Dog
```

Answer (score 3):

***option 1***
`stack` then `nlargest`

```
df.stack().nlargest(1)

Cat  Zebra    3
dtype: int64
```

---

***option 2***
`stack` then `idxmax`

```
df.stack().idxmax()

('Cat', 'Zebra')
```