# Calculating the frequency of each word in the transition matrix, using numpy and pandas only

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, frequency

I am trying to calculate the frequency of each word in the transition matrix, using numpy and pandas only.

I have a string

```
star_wars = [('darth', 'leia'), ('luke', 'han'), ('chewbacca', 'luke'), 
         ('chewbacca', 'obi'), ('chewbacca', 'luke'), ('leia', 'luke')]
```

I build a matrix for this string, using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62946067/create-a-frequency-matrix-for-bigrams-from-a-list-of-tuples-using-numpy-or-pand).

```
             chewbacca  darth  han  leia  luke  obi
chewbacca          0      0    0     0     2    1
darth              0      0    0     1     0    0
han                0      0    0     0     1    0
leia               0      0    0     0     1    0
luke               0      0    0     0     0    0
obi                0      0    0     0     0    0
```

Now I am trying to convert these values of words into probabilities, using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47297585/building-a-transition-matrix-using-words-in-python-numpy):

Using a crosstab works for the initial dataframe, but gives me pairs only

```
pd.crosstab(pd.Series(star_wars[1:]),
        pd.Series(star_wars[:-1]), normalize = 1)
```

Output is wrong and this also does not work for my created matrix, just an example:

```
col_0   (chewbacca, luke)   (chewbacca, obi)    (darth, leia)   (luke, han)
row_0               
(chewbacca, luke)   0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
(chewbacca, obi)    0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0
(leia, luke)        0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0
(luke, han)         0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
```

I also create a function

```
from itertools import islice

def my_function(seq, n = 2):
it = iter(seq)
result = tuple(islice(it, n))
if len(result) == n:
    yield result
for elem in it:
    result = result[1:] + (elem,)
    yield result
```

Apply the function and calculate probabilities

```
pairs = pd.DataFrame(my_function(star_wars), columns=['Columns', 'Rows'])
counts = pairs.groupby('Columns')['Rows'].value_counts()
probs = (counts/counts.sum()).unstack()

print(probs)
```

But it gives me the calculation of pairs (not even sure it is correct)

```
Rows               (chewbacca, luke)  (chewbacca, obi)  (leia, luke)  \
Columns                                                                
(chewbacca, luke)                NaN               0.2           0.2   
(chewbacca, obi)                 0.2               NaN           NaN   
(darth, leia)                    NaN               NaN           NaN   
(luke, han)                      0.2               NaN           NaN   

Rows               (luke, han)  
Columns                         
(chewbacca, luke)          NaN  
(chewbacca, obi)           NaN  
(darth, leia)              0.2  
(luke, han)                NaN
```

Another attempt, just using `crosstab`

**Desired about - a matrix with probabilities, not numbers.**

For example

```
            chewbacca  darth  han  leia  luke  obi
chewbacca          0      0    0     0   0.66 0.33
darth              0      0    0     1     0    0
han                0      0    0     0     1    0
leia               0      0    0     0     1    0
luke               0      0    0     0     0    0
obi                0      0    0     0     0    0
```

Appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can still do it by `crosstab`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(star_wars)
s=pd.crosstab(df[0],df[1],normalize='index')
s=s.reindex(index=df.stack().unique(),fill_value=0).reindex(columns=df.stack().unique(),fill_value=0)
s
1          darth  leia      luke  han  chewbacca       obi
0                                                         
darth          0   1.0  0.000000  0.0          0  0.000000
leia           0   0.0  1.000000  0.0          0  0.000000
luke           0   0.0  0.000000  1.0          0  0.000000
han            0   0.0  0.000000  0.0          0  0.000000
chewbacca      0   0.0  0.666667  0.0          0  0.333333
obi            0   0.0  0.000000  0.0          0  0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the probabilities from the transition matrix, you need only divide each row by the row sums.

```py
>>> df / df.values.sum(axis=1).reshape((-1,1))
           chewbacca  darth  han  leia      luke       obi
chewbacca        0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.666667  0.333333
darth            0.0    0.0  0.0   1.0  0.000000  0.000000
han              0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  1.000000  0.000000
leia             0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  1.000000  0.000000
luke             NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN
obi              NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Of course, you should be sure to not divide by zero in the last two rows.
If the row sum is zero, then all entries of the row are zero, so you replace those row sums with anything you want.

```
>>> row_sums = df.values.sum(axis=1)
>>> row_sums[row_sums == 0] = 1
>>> df / row_sums.reshape((-1,1))
           chewbacca  darth  han  leia      luke       obi
chewbacca        0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.666667  0.333333
darth            0.0    0.0  0.0   1.0  0.000000  0.000000
han              0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  1.000000  0.000000
leia             0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  1.000000  0.000000
luke             0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.000000  0.000000
obi              0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort! I wish I could accept your answer too!