# Fixing probabilities, which do not sum to 1 in the matrix of words

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, probability

I created a matrix, using answers from these questions - [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62946067/create-a-frequency-matrix-for-bigrams-from-a-list-of-tuples-using-numpy-or-pand) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62946067/create-a-frequency-matrix-for-bigrams-from-a-list-of-tuples-using-numpy-or-pand). Similar questions about this error did not help to resolve.

But probabilities exceed 1 - **ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1**

**Please let me know how can I share with you a piece of the df for the reproducibility.**

I generated the concurrence matrix, using this code

```
# Create matrix
my_df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns = words, index = words)
for k,v in frequency_list.items():
my_df.at[k[0],k[1]] = v
```

which gives me the matrix 10000*10000.

Then I converted into frequencies

```
row_sums = my_df.values.sum(axis = 1)
row_sums[row_sums == 0] = 1
my_prob = my_df/row_sums.reshape((-1,1)) 
my_prob
```

When I print one word

```
my_prob.sum().tail(30)
```

I have a probability above 1.

```
“thy               0.000000
“till              0.002538
**“to              1.109681**
```

Tried to normalize

Pick the word the and generate a list

```
word_the = my_string_prob['the'].tolist()
```

Try to normalize probabilities

```
sum_of_elements = sum(word_the)
a = 1/sum_of_elements
my_probs_scaled = [e*a for e in word_the]
my_probs_scaled
sum(my_probs_scaled)
### Output 1.000000000000005
```

This code worked on a smaller matrix, which was not so big and complex in one of questions above.
Thanks!

Comment: You can use `from decimal import Decimal as D` to avoid floating point errors

Comment: @ParthShah, thanks any tips where to use it in my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the precision of your floating point numbers using decimal in python. Consider the following as an example:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D
from decimal import getcontext
getcontext().prec = 8

word_the = [9, 4, 5, 4]
sum_of_elements = sum(word_the)
a = D(1/sum_of_elements)
my_probs_scaled = [D(e)*a for e in word_the]
print(my_probs_scaled)
print(sum(my_probs_scaled))
```

And the output is:

```
[Decimal('0.40909091'), Decimal('0.18181818'), Decimal('0.22727273'), Decimal('0.18181818')]
1.0000000
```

You can play around with the parameters, including the precision.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'

Comment: Works on my machine. Strange. Editing it, you can try again.

Comment: Decimal('0E-55'), Decimal('0E-55'), Decimal('0E-55'), Decimal('0E-55'), Decimal('0E-55'), Decimal('0E-55'), Decimal('0.0030873908')]
1.0000004 - as you can see, worked this time, but still above 1 :(

Comment: Yes, that's because the precision is 8. If you lower it to, say 6, does it work?