# Normalise numpy array / occurrence matrix "across the diagonal"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I'm trying to make an normalise a co-occurrence matrix (I supposed it's called?)
I have the following data sample coming in from a csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
                    'B':[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
                    'C':[0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],
                    'D':[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
                    'E':[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]})
```

... and I have used the following approach to create this matrix:
([Constructing a co-occurrence matrix in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574257/constructing-a-co-occurrence-matrix-in-python-pandas))

```
df_asint = df.astype(int)
coocc = df_asint.T.dot(df_asint)
print(coocc)
```

Output:

```
[4975 rows x 5 columns]
   A  B  C  D  E
A  7  6  4  6  5
B  6  6  3  5  4
C  4  3  5  4  4
D  6  5  4  7  5
E  5  4  4  5  6
```

Now the problem. I'm trying to normalise these to the **diagonal**.
I have solved it using Excel, as you can see on the screenshot.

Any thoughts on how to do this in pandas?

[image: Solution in Excel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

>>> coocc.divide(np.diag(coocc))

          A         B    C         D         E
A  1.000000  1.000000  0.8  0.857143  0.833333
B  0.857143  1.000000  0.6  0.714286  0.666667
C  0.571429  0.500000  1.0  0.571429  0.666667
D  0.857143  0.833333  0.8  1.000000  0.833333
E  0.714286  0.666667  0.8  0.714286  1.000000
```

If you want to force the upper-diagonal values to zero, you can do:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.tril(coocc.divide(np.diag(coocc))), columns=coocc.columns, index=coocc.index)

          A         B    C         D    E
A  1.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0
B  0.857143  1.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0
C  0.571429  0.500000  1.0  0.000000  0.0
D  0.857143  0.833333  0.8  1.000000  0.0
E  0.714286  0.666667  0.8  0.714286  1.0
```