# How to efficiently transform df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, transform

I have the following df:

```
          CUI1      CUI2  tot
0     C0000699  C3894683    2
1     C0000699  C0101725    1
2     C0000699  C1882413    3
...        ...       ...  ...
9995  C0000715  C0026382   56
9996  C0000715  C0010334   101
...
```

which I need to transform into a co-occurrence matrix:

```
          C0000699 C3894683 C0101725 C1882413 ... C0026382
C0000699  0        2        1        3            m
...
C3894683  2        0        n        p        ... q
...
etc..
```

The df is extremely large (~11 m rows), and I have tried looping through it to set columns (using `unstack` and `get_level`, etc.), but it is taking an inordinate amount of time and memory.  Also, note, that pairs that have a count of 0 `tot` are not given in the initial stacked df.

Any vectorized solutions to speed this up and lower the memory footprint? The closest I could find was this [constructing-a-co-occurrence-matrix-in-python-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574257/constructing-a-co-occurrence-matrix-in-python-pandas), but the df is structured differently.

Comment: How is performance with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html)?

Comment: Quite well! To be honest, I didn't even think of the simple solution:

`cooc.pivot_table(values='tot', index=['CUI1'], columns="CUI2")`

Comment: with `fill_value=0`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
df.pivot_table(index='CUI1',columns='CUI2',values='tot')
```

Comment: See above, I already got the solution.