# pyspark.pandas API: construct co-occurrence matrix, .dot() does not support dataframe as input

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to construct co-occurrence matrix of my dataframe on Databricks using pyspark.pandas API.

I tried this method to construct the matrix.
[Constructing a co-occurrence matrix in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574257/constructing-a-co-occurrence-matrix-in-python-pandas)

The code is working fine in pandas, but is throwing error with pyspark.pandas

```
coocc = psdf.T.dot(psdf)
coocc
```

I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: Unsupported type DataFrame
```

I checked the doc. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.dot.html

```
pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.dot()
```

Takes series as input.

I tried to converting dataframe to series using `psdf.squeeze()`, it does not convert dataframe to series, as my dataframe has multiple columns.

Is there any way to change `pyspark.pandas.Dataframe` to `pyspark.pandas.Series`?
Or Different method in pyspark.pandas to construct cooccurrence matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `csr_matrix` as dataframe has '1' and '0' as values

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

psdfx = sp.csr_matrix(psdf.astype(int).values)
psdfc = ptdfx.T * psdfx
psdfc.setdiag(0)
coocc = ps.DataFrame(psdfc.todense(), columns=psdf.columns, index=psdf.columns)
coocc
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840528/19642283