# Divide each row by a vector element with floating value precision

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose i have

`a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))`

and i want to divide each row with a vector

`n = np.array([1.1,2.2,3.3])`

I tried the proposed solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602187/numpy-divide-each-row-by-a-vector-element) but the fractional value is not taken into account.

Comment: Use `np.true_divide`.

Comment: @Divakar pls answer the question so I can give you credits thanks

Comment: You would learn more if you try to answer your own question. So, please do so, if you  could. Feel free to use the comment and online docs on how to use it.

Comment: When I executed `a / n` on my interpreter (anaconda 2.7) I think I got your desired result. When you say "the fractional value is not taken into account", do you mean you're getting results from integer division?

Comment: An other workaround is to generate a float array with arange(9.0) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question differently from the comments above:

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.arange(12).reshape((4,3))
print a

n = np.array([[1.1,2.2,3.3]])
print n

print a/n
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]
[[ 1.1  2.2  3.3]]
[[ 0.          0.45454545  0.60606061]
 [ 2.72727273  1.81818182  1.51515152]
 [ 5.45454545  3.18181818  2.42424242]
 [ 8.18181818  4.54545455  3.33333333]]
```

I also changed from a symmetric matrix (3x3) to (3x4) to point out that row vs columns matter. Also the divisor is a column vector now (double brackets).