# Numpy: Code independent of dimensionality of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

I have a function that takes a numpy array. I know it to be either of shape
(1,C), or (R,C)

What I need is to divide every entry by the sum of its according column.
I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602187/numpy-divide-each-row-by-a-vector-element#_=_), and the accepted answer works if I get a array of (R,C). However, with a (1,C) array, I try to access a scalar with a dimension that does not exist, throwing an error.
Is there a way to make this work independent of the dimension of the array?
See my code below:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    sums = np.sum(x, axis = 0)
    return (x / sums[None,:])



scores = np.array([[1.0, 2, 3, 6],
                   [2, 4, 5, 6],
                   [3, 8, 7, 6]])

print f(scores)
print f(np.array([1,2,3]))
```

I know why the error occurs (sums is just a scalar in the second function call), but how do I get this to work without a bunch of if-statements?

I'm pretty new to numpy, so forgive me, I don't really know what to google for.

Comment: You problem array has shape (3,), not (1,3). Print the shape to see for yourself.

Comment: @hpaulj is correct, try... x = np.atleast_2d(np.array([1,2,3])) which yields ...  x.shape => (1, 3)

Comment: Can you give your expected output? I think you might want `keepdims` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `x / np.sum(x, axis=0)`? `[None,:]` has no useful effect here, and only serves to throw an error in the 1D case.