# np.nan_to_num causes error RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've got some data in np.ndarrays that I want to normalise to be between 0 and 1. I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793045/dynamically-normalise-2d-numpy-array) what the best way to do it was, and how to avoid dividing by 0, and someone told me the best way was to use np.nan_to_num().
That seemed to work, I don't think I had any problems with it.
Since that previous question, my code has evolved, and I now want to do the same thing with the three different arrays trainingsignals, validationsignals and testsignals:

```
TrainingSigMaxes = np.max(trainingsignals, axis = 1)
TrainingNormSignals=np.nan_to_num(trainingsignals/TrainingSigMaxes[:,np.newaxis])

ValidationSigMaxes = np.max(validationsignals, axis = 1)
ValidationNormSignals=np.nan_to_num(validationsignals/ValidationSigMaxes[:,np.newaxis])

TestSigMaxes = np.max(testsignals, axis = 1)
TestNormSignals=np.nan_to_num(testsignals/TestSigMaxes[:,np.newaxis])
```

But when I run the code it gives me the error message: "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide".

Can anyone help me solve this issue?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a warning. You will still get the 'approximately correct' output.

If you want to hide warnings, you could run this beforehand:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

or for more customization, you could refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings).

> Note : 'Approximately correct' value is based on the function
> `numpy.nan_to_num`. You could refer the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html).